# Populate picklist dynamically based on filepath type in Azure Devops?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, picklist

In Azure Devops, I am building one extension with build task where input picklist field is dependent on the another input filepath field. 
When the user provides an input filepath, I wanted to dynamically read and populate the picklist with new items.
I tried to search and implement but couldn't find a way. 
Any help or guidance will be appreciated. I found the below example to help me out for static values.

```
{
   "name": "action",
   "type": "pickList",
   "label": "Action",
   "defaultValue": "Publish",
   "required": true,
   "helpMarkDown": "Select the Action to perform",
   "options": {
     "Publish": "Publish Changes",
     "Script": "Script Changes",
     "DeployReport": "Generate Deployment Report"
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The out-of-box tasks are open source, so you can take a look through the [repository](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks) to get some ideas of the patterns they use.  Here is an example from the [Download Build Artifacts task](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/DownloadBuildArtifactsV0/task.json#L182).  The build definition is dependent on the project that is defined.

```
{
        "name": "project",
        "type": "pickList",
        "label": "Project",
        "defaultValue": "",
        "required": true,
        "visibleRule": "buildType == specific",
        "properties": {
            "EditableOptions": "True",
            "DisableManageLink": "True"
        },
        "helpMarkDown": "The project from which to download the build artifacts"
    },
    {
        "name": "definition",
        "aliases": [
            "pipeline"
        ],
        "type": "pickList",
        "label": "Build pipeline",
        "defaultValue": "",
        "required": true,
        "visibleRule": "buildType == specific",
        "properties": {
            "EditableOptions": "True",
            "DisableManageLink": "True",
            "IsSearchable": "True"
        },
        "helpMarkDown": "Select the build pipeline name"
    },
```

Then in the dataSourceBindings section believe it uses the target from the previous selection as a parameter input.

```
"dataSourceBindings": [
    {
        "endpointId": "tfs:teamfoundation",
        "target": "project",
        "endpointUrl": "{{endpoint.url}}/_apis/projects?$skip={{skip}}&$top=1000",
        "resultSelector": "jsonpath:$.value[?(@.state=='wellFormed')]",
        "resultTemplate": "{ \"Value\" : \"{{{id}}}\", \"DisplayValue\" : \"{{{name}}}\" }",
        "callbackContextTemplate": "{\"skip\": \"{{add skip 1000}}\"}",
        "callbackRequiredTemplate": "{{isEqualNumber result.count 1000}}",
        "initialContextTemplate": "{\"skip\": \"0\"}"
    },
    {
        "endpointId": "tfs:teamfoundation",
        "target": "definition",
        "endpointUrl": "{{endpoint.url}}/{{project}}/_apis/build/definitions?api-version=3.0-preview&$top=500&continuationToken={{{continuationToken}}}&name=*{{name}}*&queryOrder=2",
        "resultSelector": "jsonpath:$.value[?(@.quality=='definition')]",
        "parameters": {
            "project": "$(project)",
            "name": "$(name)"
        },
        "resultTemplate": "{ \"Value\" : \"{{{id}}}\", \"DisplayValue\" : \"{{{name}}}\" }",
        "callbackContextTemplate": "{\"continuationToken\" : \"{{{headers.x-ms-continuationtoken}}}\"}",
        "callbackRequiredTemplate": "{{{#headers.x-ms-continuationtoken}}}true{{{/headers.x-ms-continuationtoken}}}",
        "initialContextTemplate": "{\"continuationToken\" : \"{{{system.utcNow}}}\"}"
    },
```

Comment: If we don't have any specific API and it's closer to XML format, do we still have an option of selecting endpoints? Can we access the source code file from the API?